# How to force wifi password update on windows machine?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, ssid

I have a strange thing happening in my home WiFi network. I updated my SSID and password on the WIFI router. All the connected devices lost the connection and I had to reconnect them by entering new password.

One of my friends machines which was previously connected in my network did not loose WiFi.

It automatically updated SSID and WiFi password and kept the internet connection on. How is this possible?

How can I force his machine to drop the WiFi so that he can be asked to enter SSID/password again?

I am basically trying to kick his machine out of my WiFi network :)

Answer (score 0):

Login to your router in a browser, find your friends machine, and block their MAC address through a MAC filter.